# Parameter object is improperly defined

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

The following is my VBScript code in a classic ASP application:

```
    Set newParam = command.CreateParameter(Name, ParamType, 1)
    newParam.Value = Value
    command.Parameters.Append(newParam)
    command.Parameters(Name) = Value
```

The 'Append' line always breaks with the following error:

[image]

It seems to make no difference whether the command has a valid active connection or whether the connection is open (the connection is to an Oracle database).

The 'Name', 'ParamType' and 'Value' parameter values are correct.

What is missing? Or could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: second line is not needed (newParam.Value = Value)

Comment: What exactly is the value for `ParamType`? You're not specifying a Size, which may be required for the data type you select.

Comment: Instead of `command.Parameters.Append` have you considered `command.Parameters.Refresh` ? This might save you a lot of effort.

Comment: I would aldo look into two other things: 1) I have seen many debuggers (VS 2008) report one line off. I.e. try to verify if that is the erroring line, and not the CreateParameter., and 2) are the constants for param type, if you're using constants, in scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from the `Append` instruction. In this context their meaning is "pass argument by value", not "parameter list" (see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx)). Also put the value assignment after the parameter assignment.

```
Set newParam = command.CreateParameter(Name, ParamType, 1)
command.Parameters.Append newParam
newParam.Value = Value
```

Do you still receive the error with the `Append` instruction? If so, something is wrong with your `Name` or `ParamType` arguments.

Comment: Removing the parentheses when calling Subs is good advice in general, but I'm not sure it makes a difference here. Whether or not your pass the argument ByVal or ByRef, it's still going to be a reference to the same Parameter object.

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel Most likely it won't make a difference (it didn't when I tested with some sample values), but I'd remove them anyway, just to be on the safe side.